# How to view all the created databases in a Oracle DBMS

Tags: oracle

How to view all the created databases in a Oracle DBMS ?

Comment: What you mean by database is not clear? Do you mean the list of Oracle instances that can be reached from a client, list of schemas in a perticular instance...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using following query in oracle:

```
select * from user_tablespaces;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you about schemas:
    select * from dba_users

But database is instance